# Oracle Forms 10g users disconnecting randomly with error FRM-92102

Tags: oracle, apache, oracle10g

We are facing an issue with our web based Oracle 10g Forms application.

Clients are getting disconnected randomly (It can be 1 minute to 3 hours after logging into the application).

Application Server - Windows Server 2003 R2 running Oracle Forms 10g

Database Server - Linux server also running Oracle DB

At the time of the event, we are getting the below log in Apache error log.

[Sat Aug 15 10:26:35 2015] [error] [client ClientIP] [ecid: 1439623595:AppServerIP:2760:3216:6822,0] MOD_OC4J_0015: recv() returns 0. There has no message available to be received and oc4j has gracefully (orderly) closed the connection.

[Sat Aug 15 10:26:35 2015] [error] [client ClientIP] [ecid: 1439623595:AppServerIP:2760:3216:6822,0] MOD_OC4J_0054: Failed to call network routine to receive an ajp13 message from oc4j.

[Sat Aug 15 10:26:35 2015] [error] [client ClientIP] [ecid: 1439623595:AppServerIP:2760:3216:6822,0] MOD_OC4J_0033: Failed to receive an ajp13 message from oc4j.

[Sat Aug 15 10:26:35 2015] [error] [client ClientIP] [ecid: 1439623595:AppServerIP:2760:3216:6822,0] MOD_OC4J_0121: Failed to service request with network worker: OC4J_BI_Forms_15 and it is not recoverable.

[Sat Aug 15 10:26:35 2015] [error] [client ClientIP] [ecid: 1439623595:AppServerIP:2760:3216:6822,0] MOD_OC4J_0013: Failed to call destination: OC4J_BI_Forms's service() to service the request.

Also, I can see the below error in Application.log (not sure it is related)

15/08/15 10:38:19 formsweb: Forms session <204> aborted: unable to communicate with runtime process.

15/08/15 10:38:19 formsweb: Forms session <204> exception stack trace:

java.io.IOException: FRM-93000: Unexpected internal error.

Details : Invalid or absent Content-Length from runform

at oracle.forms.servlet.ListenerServlet.forwardResponseFromRunform(Unknown Source)

at oracle.forms.servlet.ListenerServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:835)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:341)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:816)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:231)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:136)

at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:192)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)

We have tested the network and there is no ping drop at the time of the error from client  to the app server or database server. And the port 12502 is also open on the application server.

Does anyone has experinced this kind of error before?
What are the meanings of these logs?

#### Update netstat -s results on Application Server (2003 R2)

```
IPv4 Statistics

  Packets Received                   = 771212
  Received Header Errors             = 0
  Received Address Errors            = 1435
  Datagrams Forwarded                = 0
  Unknown Protocols Received         = 0
  Received Packets Discarded         = 322
  Received Packets Delivered         = 769487
  Output Requests                    = 779485
  Routing Discards                   = 0
  Discarded Output Packets           = 0
  Output Packet No Route             = 0
  Reassembly Required                = 0
  Reassembly Successful              = 0
  Reassembly Failures                = 0
  Datagrams Successfully Fragmented  = 4
  Datagrams Failing Fragmentation    = 0
  Fragments Created                  = 8

ICMPv4 Statistics

                            Received    Sent
  Messages                  5912        5912
  Errors                    0           0
  Destination Unreachable   0           0
  Time Exceeded             0           0
  Parameter Problems        0           0
  Source Quenches           0           0
  Redirects                 0           0
  Echos                     5902        10
  Echo Replies              10          5902
  Timestamps                0           0
  Timestamp Replies         0           0
  Address Masks             0           0
  Address Mask Replies      0           0

TCP Statistics for IPv4

  Active Opens                        = 18140
  Passive Opens                       = 23088
  Failed Connection Attempts          = 149
  Reset Connections                   = 674
  Current Connections                 = 220
  Segments Received                   = 756872
  Segments Sent                       = 771596
  Segments Retransmitted              = 463

UDP Statistics for IPv4

  Datagrams Received    = 6522
  No Ports              = 575
  Receive Errors        = 267
  Datagrams Sent        = 1504
```

Comment: Check the TNS Listeners log, and database alerts. You might possibly need to increase the trace levels in the TNS logs (server and client).    Use "netstat -s" for packet drops. In the 2 projects I have worked on with this type of issues both have been found to be caused by a faulty NIC or faulty network driver. WE even got this on 2 servers with the same hardware - turned out the NICs on both were from a faulty batch.

Comment: Thanks. We have changed the NIC port on the servers and tested, still the error is there. I will reinstall the drivers on both servers today.

I've edited the question to include netstat -s results.

Answer (score 0):

The netstat -s needs to be run periodically and to check the value(s) for dropped packets etc over time.

I was on Metalink and had a look at your issue. If you have access to MetaLink (or My Oracle Support) try to search for Note 300232.1. Here is what it says:

> As a result of these bugs , report requests get resubmitted after the
>   timeout period in httpd.conf. These resubmitted requests are routed to
>   different OC4J islands, giving rise to instability.
>
> SOLUTION
>
> 1) Set  timeout value in httpd.conf to a value greater than the
>   execution time of the Reports
>   REFERENCES
>
> NOTE:294749.1 - Troubleshooting WebForms Tuning / Performance /Time out Problems

There is also a reference to a comprehensive Note:

> Troubleshooting WebForms 10g Tuning / Performance /Time out Problems
>   (Doc ID 294749.1)

On the HTTP side it the target parameters to tune are:

```
- KeepAlive 
- MaxClient
- MinSpareServers 
- MaxSpareServers
- KeepAliveTimeout 
- MaxRequestsPerChild
- ThreadLimit
- ThreadsPerChild
- Global-thread-pool
```

OC4J parameters:

```
- Xconcurrentio
- Xms(sizem) -Xmx(sizem)
- Xss
- OC4J Load Balancing 
- client 
- server
- session-timeout
- Xconcurrentio
```

Forms Tuning:

```
prestartInit
prestartMin
prestartIncrement
prestartTimeout
```

Comment: Timeour value in Apache httpd.conf is set to 300 now. Still the error is there. We have tried the below suggestions which made the error less frequent. But still it shows.

http://oracleformsinfo.com/2012/01/12/forms_timeout-frm-92101/